# Treating error message in jquery ajax call

Tags: php, jquery

I have an ajax call as below:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "process.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function( response ) {
                    $('#in-progress').hide();
                  $('#mydiv').html(response)
                  .append("")                   
                }                     

              });
```

What I want is, that I need to get the distinguished message from process.php. What should I do in thid regard so that I may not parse the message myself. I need to send some specific code or something from my process.php so that the ajax can process it separately. Shall I use some http response code and use it in statusCode ? What is the appropriate practice to do that ?

e.g. Success message will be "This is Success"
Error message will be "There is an unknown error" - This message should be treated separately. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do to distinguish a success/error status from an ajax call, I return http status 500 with the error message encoded in json.

The error status 500 is being handled by the 'error' callback which I usually set on the $.ajaxSetup like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  'error': function( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
     var data = $.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
     // alert somehow.
},
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you could but you have to use json.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "process.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType:   'json',
                success: function( response ) {
                    $('#in-progress').hide();
                  $('#mydiv').html(response)
                  .append("")                   
                }                     

              });
```

and if success  in your response.php return your array in json. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php,

imagine on your array

```
response.php

arr['success'] = true;
arr['message'] = 'Your good solution"
arr['code'] = 'Your code':
json_encode(arr);
```

and in js success:

```
if response.success == 'true'
 alert('good' + response.code);
else
 alert('bad' + response.code);
end
```

I think is something approach that what you need

Comment: to me both answer looks good and practical. thanks both of you, but I could only accept answer :)